# Foreign key refering to multiple tables

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key, vertical-partitioning

I have 4 tables

```
A(ida, name)
B(ida, B-specific stuff)
C(ida, C-specific stuff)
D(ida, D-specific stuff)
```

and i want that another table E could refer to just B OR C (not D). What can i write in the

```
CREATE TABLE E
```

?

Comment: What's the significance of `A`? Do `B`, `C` and `D` inherit from it? Does `E` also need to inherit from it and the relationship you described is unrelated to inheritance altogether, or it needs to inherit from `B` or `C` (or even the other way around)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you are trying to use some kind of supertype/subtype -- as opposed to simple vertical partitioning. If so, do introduce a type-discriminator.

Because this is generic example (A, B, C, D ..) it is hard to guess what relates to what, so here are two options as my best guess.

---

**Option 1**

[image]

---

**Option 2**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `check` constraint to enforce that `D` only references `B` or `C`:

```
create table D
    (
    id int constraint PK_D primary key,
    idb int constraint FK_D_IDB foreign key references B(id),
    idc int constraint FK_D_IDC foreign key references C(id),
    constraint CHK_D_B_OR_C check 
        (
        case when idb is null then 0 else 1 end + 
        case when idc is null then 0 else 1 end = 1
        )
    );
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/999e9/3/0)

Comment: but i'd like that it refers to B or to C, not to both of them (and i don't think that a null fk in each row is efficient.

Comment: Is it better in your way or with a unique table `A(ida, ..., where)`? I just did 2 month of "lessons of sql/mysql" and we didn-t do very much, so i was thinking to to in this way before asking, and in the site i'm doing i can check that where must be B or C, and then i can check with a trigger if i'm inserting into E a raw with D.

Comment: Triggers are evil, I'd stay away from them.  Two foreign keys is usually better than a "type" column, because the type column repeats the information in the foreign keys.

Comment: Well, it would be just a check to check (lol) that the type colums isn't D. Why should't i use it? THere wouldn't be other trigger activated after this one.